# Read a Flashing Led in Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino

So it's a simple problem, I have several LEDs on a board where depending on their states it will trigger a command to fire a relay. Where I am stuck is figuring out how to get the Arduino to see a blinking LED, I have tried to bypass it all together but the code got larger than we wanted so it was scrapped and I am starting all over. Any ideas would be most helpful. Here is the basic code:

```
int Relay = 2;
int Led = 7;
int Ball = 8;

void setup() 
{
 Serial.begin(115200);
 pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Led, INPUT);
 pinMode(Ball, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  digitalWrite (Relay, HIGH);
  delay (500);
  digitalWrite (Relay, LOW);
  delay(300);
  digitalRead(Led);
 
  if(Led == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(Ball, HIGH); 
  }
  if(Led == LOW)
  {
    digitalWrite(Ball, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Define "blinking"  Do you mean detecting it was "off" to "on" to "off" with a delay in between, or perhaps something else?  Your code will only see "LOW" as written I believe.

Comment: If you need to have one part of the program blink it and another part read it, you may need to use threads or interrupts to allow it to do more than 1 thing at a time.  Or do some serious FSM work where it never blocks for long.

Comment: `digitalRead(Led);` You are ignoring the returned value. You can combine to: `if (digitalRead(Led) == HIGH) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: I don't expect you are reading the led. I expect you have an input to your Arduino tied to the same place where the led is connected.

Comment: Apologies all, the code I have listed is not for the blinking Led that is in fact looking at a steady on/off led, What I am looking for is when the blinking Led begins its process of Blinking then I will use to execute a Relay command to trigger a physical event.

Answer (score 1):

`digitalRead(Led)` throws away the value you are reading, and `if (Led == LOW)` is comparing a pin number with a voltage level, which is meaningless.  You mean:

`level = digitalRead(Led);`
`if (level == HIGH) {` ...

Comment: I apologize, I should have annotated the code so everyone knew what was going on, what you see works for triggering relay(Ball) perfectly, what I am after is I have an Led that is either in a blinking state or off, when it is blinking I need to trigger another Relay, so how do I see a blinking Led.

Comment: You can't "see" anything really, you can only read the voltage level that you set with `digitalWrite()` using `digitalRead()` (but doing so correctly as I described above). This will tell you that the level is high when the LED is on and low when it is not. There is no special "blinking" state. If your program is the one controlling the LED, then you're the one who needs that part of the program doing the blinking to communicate with the part that needs to know. We're not here to teach basic programming skills.

Comment: Im not blinking an Led, I need a Pin from the Arduino to see its state, thus far I have been unable to read that Pin with digital read, im not sure if the Led is blinking too fast or I need to go about another way.

Comment: Then sounds like you're SOL. The code here shows how to read the pin, but "blinking" is not a state that can be read. Unless you want to sit on the pin for 2-3 seconds taking multiple samples and interpreting the results. What made you think this was possible?

Comment: the "pulseIn" command, if I understand its for reading a PWM or signal, a blinking Led is exactly that a signal of Highs and Lows, but I thank you all for your help I have reached out to my old instructor and we figured it out.

Comment: Ah, yes, if the line is PWM rather than digital, and the frequency is low enough for meaningfull blinking, that might be readable.